# How does androidx app startup improve the cold start time?

Tags: android, androidx, android-jetpack

In newly released library of `App startup` in android jetpack , I am confused in the point of `Content Provider` what is the role of the content provider while initializing the library when the application starts ? Can anyone explain in brief about this?

Comment: [Because onCreate of CP is called before onCreate of Application class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11788838/why-does-contentprovider-oncreate-get-called-before-application-oncreate)

Answer (score 2):

App Startup provides a more performant way to initialize components at app startup and explicitly define their dependencies. which is better than using content providers

Comment: what is the role of content providers in app libraries initialization?