# Content Provider's onCreate getting called before I tried accessing it

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

According to the
[Official documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProvider#onCreate())

onCreate() method of the content provider is called by Android's system call immediately after it creates the provider. And since the provider isn't created until a ContentResolver object tries to access it.
How my onCreate is getting called before I tried accessing it using contentResolver? (Note: I am not even accessing the provider still its onCreate getting called)

Comment: `And since the provider isn't created until a ContentResolver object tries to access it.` Well that is not true.

Comment: Why is it a problem?

Comment: @blackapps check this out https://shorturl.at/fEV58 I have quoted it from the official docs.

Comment: @zomega i am having some confusion as the documentation says otherwise.
`Oncreate - Initialize your provider. The Android system calls this method immediately after it creates your provider. Your provider isn't created until a ContentResolver object tries to access it.`

Comment: When exactly is your onCreate called? You did not give this info.

Comment: The [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-creating#RequiredAccess) saying it's created when there is a ContentResolver is probably simply out-dated. The [other](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProvider#onCreate()) documentation saying it's created on app startup seems to be the current one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for `Provider.onCreate()` that you linked to **explicitly states**:

> Implement this to initialize your content provider on startup. This
> method is called for all registered content providers on the
> application main thread at application launch time.

So Android will call `onCreate()` on all content providers immediately on application launch. Obviously it cannot call `onCreate()` until the content provider is instantiated, so that means that immediately on application launch, Android will instantiate all content providers and call `onCreate()` on all of them.

Your application will have to deal with this appropriately.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Please check this documentation as well. 
https://shorturl.at/fEV58 - It says
`onCreate - Initialize your provider. The Android system calls this method immediately after it creates your provider. Your provider isn't created until a ContentResolver object tries to access it. `

Comment: Well, as usual, the Android documentation is not 100% correct :-( And it often contradicts itself. If you are seeing the `Provider.onCreate()` being called at application initialization, then the documentation isn't correct. You should set a breakpoint in your content provider's `onCreate()` and see if you can tell from the stack frame where it is called from. This would help to understand what is going on.

Comment: Have a look at these related questions, they validate my assumptions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11788838/why-does-contentprovider-oncreate-get-called-before-application-oncreate/11858493#11858493 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3483977/when-is-a-contentprovider-really-created or you could just search the Internet for "when do contentproviders get created"

Comment: And it looks like content providers are actually instantiated **before** `Application.onCreate()` is even called.

Comment: And this bug report is also relevant/interesting: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36917845

Comment: can you look into the following issue:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77515050/reading-json-file-from-assets-in-androids-native-library

Answer (score 1):

One never has to start/launch the app that comes with a content provider.

The provider will do its job without the app ever started.

As soon as the app is installed.

So expect your onCreate() to be called at install too.