# Reading json file from assets in Android's Native Library

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I am trying to read a JSON file from assets folder in the apk using ([Asset NDK apis](https://developer.android.com/ndk/reference/group/asset))

I am using `AAssetManager_fromJava` to use Dalvik AssetManager object on native side.

But since I need to load the JSON file in JNI_Onload, and it gets called before the onCreate method of application components. I get null NullPointerException while calling getAssets() method (due to android.content.Context being null).

How can I resolve this issue?

PS: I need to load assets in JNI_Onload itself and library should be loaded within static block i.e. before onCreate is being called.

```
   public class MainActivity extends Activity {

      static {
        System.loadLibrary("nativeLibrary");
      }

     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     }


     public AssetManager getAssetManager() {
        return getAssets();
     }
    }
```

```
jobject getAssetManagerFromJava(JniEnv* env, jobject obj) {

  jclass clazz = env->GetObjectClass(obj);
  jmethodID method = env->GetMethodID(clazz, "getAssetManager", "()Landroid/content/res/AssetManager;");
  jobject ret = env->CallObjectMethod(obj, method);

  return ret;

}
```

```
  jobject jam = getAssetManagerFromJava(env, obj);
  AAssetManager* am = AAssetManager_fromJava(env, jam); // am is getting NULL (issue)
```

Comment: [Does this answer work?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46871051/1548468)

Comment: env->FindClass("android/app/ActivityThread"); unable to find this class

Comment: @Botje this worked! you can post it as an answer. btw IDE was complaining about the class not found but I think this class is not the part of public SDK/hidden that is why IDE was not able to find it. But at runtime application was able to find the class.

Comment: Update: It didn't work actually the way I wanted it to be. By mistake I was calling it after the application context was established that is why I was getting non null context. (I wanted JNI_onload to be called before any of the app component is initialized but as @David believe it is not possible)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is possible. `JNI_Onload()` is getting called **before** the Application `Context` has been established. You will need to rearchitect your code so that your access to the assets is delayed until the application `Context` has been established. To do that you could do one of the following:

- Load the native library in `Application.onCreate()`
- Add a method in your native library that gets called in `Application.onCreate()` on `MainActivity.onCreate()` to trigger reading the assets
- Modify all of the (public) methods in your native library so that they first check that the assets have been read, and if they have not yet been read they are then read immediately before trying to use them.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! btw what do you think about calling System.loadlibrary() in onCreate? is it ok to do so?

Comment: Sure. That should work fine. You can also create a custom `Application` class and call it in `onCreate()` there. The custom `Application` class will get instantiated first, before any `Activity` instances are created and it will only get instantiated once per OS process, so it behaves like a singleton.